# What does this one line script do?

Tags: linux, sed, command

```
sed -n 's/^@(#)*/    /p'
```

The input is piped in for this sed command. However, I am having tough times understanding this expresion `'s/^@(#)*/    /p'`

Comment: Matches `@(#` followed by 0 or more `)` at the start of the line, and replaces them with 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If the line starts with the string formed by the contiguous characters `@` `(` and `#` followed by the charter `)` repeated zero or more times, then that line is printed after the aforementioned string is replaced with 4 blank chars. All other lines are not printed:

```
$ cat file
X@(#)*1
@(#))))2
@(#)*3
@(#)4
@(#5
@(6

$ sed -n 's/^@(#)*/    /p' file
    2
    *3
    4
    5
```